# Custom Validators in Angularjs - $validators is not showing in link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a custom validator, but I am getting that the ctrl.$validators is undefined. Below is my code:

```
   link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {               
        ctrl.$validators.emptyCheckboxList = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
            if (!modelValue || modelValue.length === 0) {
                ctrl.$setValidity("emptyCheckboxList", false);
            }
            else {
                ctrl.$setValidity("emptyCheckboxList", true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, is there a way to override the required validator? In the documentation of AngularJS, they mentioned to override the $isEmpty, but it didn't work with me.

Thanks

Comment: Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. Use the [ng-required directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) to control the `required` attribute on an element.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Why do you want to override the `$isEmpty` function? Maybe give us an example of how you intend to use this directive?

Comment: georgeawg, I am trying to implement a checkbox list and to add a required option. The problem is that we are using in our convension sc-model instead of ng-model. Is there any solution?

Comment: Since you have accepted an answer to this question, you should open a new question.

Comment: I have created another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498179/override-angularjs-required-validator-for-a-checkbox-list-directive-using-scmode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$validators` prop is available inside [**`ngModelController`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) (controller of `ng-model` directive). It seems like you were missing to require `ngModel` in your directive definition object.

```
require: 'ngModel', //<-- this must be present here
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {               
    ctrl.$validators.emptyCheckboxList = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (!modelValue || modelValue.length === 0) {
            ctrl.$setValidity("emptyCheckboxList", false);
        }
        else {
            ctrl.$setValidity("emptyCheckboxList", true);
        }
    }
}
```

When you add `require: 'ngModel'` inside directive DDO. It avail `require` directive controller(this case [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)) inside 4th parameter of `link` function.

Comment: Is it possible to use a custom model. Example: scModel?

Comment: @TheEagle this `$validators` will only available on `ngModel`, you could use customModel, I guess you want to require multiple directive, I don;t get concern thoroughly

Comment: What exactly you eant to do with existing required validator?