# Override AngularJS required validator for a checkbox list directive using scModel (a custom model object) instead of ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am using a custom model object called scModel isntead of the ngModel in my AngularJS checkbox list directive.

Is there a way to override the required validator?

Here is the code:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'invalid': checkboxListCtrl.scModel.length === 0, 'touched': checkboxListCtrl.form[checkboxListCtrl.scName].$touched }">
<label class="input-label" ng-if="checkboxListCtrl.scLabel">
    {{checkboxListCtrl.scLabel}}
    <span ng-if="checkboxListCtrl.scRequired" class="sc-required"></span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="{{checkboxListCtrl.scName}}" ng-model="checkboxListCtrl.scModel.join()" ng-required="checkboxListCtrl.scRequired"/>
<ul class="sc-checkbox-list" name="{{checkboxListCtrl.scName}}" >
    <li ng-repeat="item in checkboxListCtrl.scItems" ng-class="{'aligned-left': checkboxListCtrl.scRepeatDirection =='horizontal'}">
        <my-checkbox sc-label="item[checkboxListCtrl.scDisplayField]"
                        sc-disabled="checkboxListCtrl.scDisabled"
                        sc-value="item[checkboxListCtrl.scValueField]"
                        sc-checked="checkboxListCtrl.scModel.indexOf(item[checkboxListCtrl.scValueField]) > -1"
                        sc-on-change="checkboxListCtrl.onCheckboxChange"
                        sc-name="{{checkboxListCtrl.scName + $index}}"
                        ></my-checkbox>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @georgeawg, I have included the code

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible dupilcate of [How to add ng-model functionality to a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594532/how-to-add-ng-model-functionality-to-a-component/44595910#44595910).